# Выбрать большое кол-во id с БД

Tags: sql, mysql

Как выбрать 4 определенных id с БД.
В таком смысле

```
    mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM posts WHERE posts.tag_id = '1', '23', '52','23'")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM posts WHERE posts.tag_id IN (1, 23, 52,23)")
```

если тип поля int. Если же строковый, то

```
mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM posts WHERE posts.tag_id IN ('1', '23', '52', '23')")
```

Answer (score 0):

Но также, если продолжая вашу логику можно сделать так, хотя это не очень удобно:

```
mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM posts WHERE posts.tag_id = '1' or posts.tag_id = '23' or posts.tag_id = '52' or posts.tag_id = '23'")
```

:-)

Comment: select * from posts where posts.tag_id in (
        select 1 union 
        select 23 union 
        select 52 union 
        select 23
    )